# Issue with upload_fileobj - ValueError: Fileobj must implement read

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, bytesio

I'm getting the following error in Glue with upload_fileobj when trying to add a file to AWS S3:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bytes  = BytesIO()
zf     = zipfile.ZipFile(bytes, "w")

for object_info in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="stg/transfer/"):
    if object_info.key[-1] == "/":
        continue
    print(object_info.key)
    obj = bucket.Object(key=object_info.key)
    o = obj.get()
    data = o["Body"].read()
    name = object_info.key.split('/')[2] + date_str + '.csv'
    zf.writestr(name, data)
    print(o)
    
zf.close()
bytes.seek(0)
s3.upload_fileobj(bytes.getvalue(), bucket , key)
```

> s3.upload_fileobj(bytes.getvalue(), bucket , key) File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 525, in upload_fileobj raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read') ValueError: Fileobj must implement read

Does anyone know what causes the error? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`upload_fileobj` accepts a file object, not a byte array. You need to put in `bytes` in place of `bytes.getvalue()`.